Double pulse testing the first transients on the current
I would like to comprehend what represents the first pulse on the ID current of the LS and HS in double pulse test configuration. I have the circuitry as shown: 
LS is my active switch, when I turn the LS on for the first time I can see a roughly 400 nC peak on the ID of LS and roughly 300 nC negative peak of the high side.


What capacities represent these two peaks?
Why is LS charge bigger
then HS charge?
What are these charge values dependent on?


Kurt Müller - Hi, Where did the schematic come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each piece of that material. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) then please [edit] the question & add the source name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the original source was a book or other offline material, [edit] the question & add a full citation e.g. title, author(s), page, edition etc. (see the linked rule for details). TY

Are these your own measurements?  What components are you testing?  How are you measuring?  Are there any other components or elements in the circuit?  (Is a 50Ω+ signal generator really appropriate for this test?)  Could you show the layout (board layout, photos of construction)?
